# reading an XML file into a workbook programmatically

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel

I want to read various types of XML file into Excel so that users can do anaysis and reporting. I can do this manually (File | Open, select file, select As a read-only workbook) but this code gives me an error:

```
Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim oBook As New Excel.Worksheet
oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.OpenXML(readFiles.Item(thisFile), , LoadOption:=1)
```

The error is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in GFF Translator.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D8-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

The XML may be in different formats but contain a number of nodes followed by a sequence of employee nodes.

- my (truncated) examples look like this

  MY TEST LTDMY TEST LIMITE
  MY TEST LTD(NONE)
  17
  MR..
  MR..
  MR..

or this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
<EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
<Header><MessageDetails><Class>HMRC-PAYE-RTI-FPS</Class><CorrelationI
<SenderDetails><IDAuthentication><SenderID>PRODUCT</SenderID></IDAuth
</Header>
<Body><IRenvelope xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/PAYE/RTI/
<FullPaymentSubmission><EmpRefs><OfficeNo>123</OfficeNo><PayeRef>ABC1
<Employee><EmployeeDetails><NINO>AA112233D</NINO><Name><Fore>AILEEN..
<Employee><EmployeeDetails><NINO>BB112233D</NINO><Name><Fore>BEATA...
<Employee><EmployeeDetails><NINO>CC112233D</NINO><Name><Fore>CERYS...
</FullPaymentSubmission></IRenvelope></Body></GovTalkMessage>
```

I really only need to extract the employee data, so maybe there is an easier way to do that?

[Edited to say: I can't get the first example to format correctly, but I'm sure you will get the idea.]

Comment: Excel.Workbooks.OpenXML returns a Workbook not a Worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned the result to a wrong object.
Excel.Workbooks.OpenXML method returns an excel workbook and not an excel worksheet

Change 
**Dim oBook As New Excel.Worksheet** to
**Dim oBook As New Excel.Workbook** and try

Comment: Duh! Couldn't see the wood for the trees... And I meant to set it as a workbook, as you can tell from the variable!